# como hacer responsive una galeria

Tags: html, css, responsive, grid

me gustaría que por ser responsive, al estar en una pantalla màs pequeña las imágenes  vayan quedando una debajo de la otra. GRACIAS

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25%, 1fr));
  
  user-select: none;
}

.card-cover {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card-cover__background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.card-cover__body {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card-cover__body:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(253, 252, 249, 0.904);
}
.card-cover__body:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>1234</title>



 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

 <div class="cards container-fluid">
  <div class="card-cover">
   <div class="card-cover__body ">
    <img class="card-cover__background" src="https://static.iris.net.co/semana/upload/images/2017/10/3/542721_1.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>
     Hola mundo
    </h2>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-cover">
   <div class="card-cover__body">
    <img class="card-cover__background" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/810x700" alt="">
    <h2>
     Hola mundo
    </h2>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-cover">
   <div class="card-cover__body">
    <img class="card-cover__background" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/700x700" alt="">
    <h2>
     Hola mundo
    </h2>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-cover">
   <div class="card-cover__body">
    <img class="card-cover__background" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/500x700" alt="">
    <h2>
     Hola mundo
    </h2>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como en este caso estás utilizando CSS Grid, para obtener lo que quieres tendrías que utilizar Media Queries.

Con esta linea de código le estás diciendo a css que quieres que tenga varias columnas:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(25%, 1fr));
```

Si quieres que las imagenes estén una debajo de la otra en pantallas pequeñas, pues en un media querie le especificas que solo quieres una sola columna. Eso hará que se pongan una debajo de otra. `grid-template-column: 1fr` dentro de un media querie puede ayudar. Ej:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .cards {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

Poniendo eso al final de tu código debería funcionar. Claro hay otras formas, pero espero hayas entendido con este ejemplo. Saludos!